# Clean monkey patching in ruby

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

I was looking at this blog entry: [3 Ways to Monkey-Patch Without Making a Mess](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/) and I noticed something strange:

> ```
> # Actually monkey-patch DateTime
> DateTime.include CoreExtensions::DateTime::BusinessDays
> ```

I've never seen this type of include before and I can't seem to find any documentation on it.  How is it supposed to work and am I still supposed to still use a require call to bring in the file?  I don't see how it could know the definite path and filename otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**include** is a [standard module method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-include) in Ruby.

You will have to require the relevant file (containing the module definition) unless you have some sort of autoloading mechanism as in Ruby on Rails.